# How do I use request.user in template

Tags: python, django

I am trying display different text to user on an empty tag. I was able to implement this correctly in other template, but I do not clearly understand why it is not displaying correctly in another template. For example, if user A login, I want only user A to see 'Find people to follow' , while other users to see 'No users'.

```
def following_view(request, username):
    p = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user__username=username)
    all_profile_user=[]
    button_status_list=[]

    for user_obj in p:
        u = user_obj.to_user
        all_profile_user.append(u)
        friend = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user, friends__id=user_obj.id).exists()
        button_status = 'none'
        if not friends:
            button_status = 'not_friend'
            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=u)) == 1:
                button_status = 'cancel_request_sent'

        button_status_list.append(button_status)
context={'profile_and_button_status':zip(p, button_status_list), 'u':all_profile_user, 'following':p,}


{% for data in profile_and_button_status %}
#Button codes here
{% empty %}
#why this doesn't display
{% if data.user != request.user %}
No users
{% endif %}
{% if data.user == request.user %}
Find people to follow
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but your code is highly inefficient. This `len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=u)) == 1` reads all related records from the db and creates a model instance for each record, just to discard the whole thing. You'd get the same functional result for way cheaper using your db's aggregration function - in this case quite simply using the `QuerySet.count()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
{% for friend_request, status in profile_and_button_status %}
#Button codes here

#why this doesn't display
{% if friend_request.to_user != user %}
No users
{% else %}
Find people to follow
{% empty %}
No users
{% endfor %}
```

But I would suggest a better approach, which is to calculate these in views instead of template. Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, CharField, F

def following_view(request, username):
    friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(
        from_user__username=username
    ).annotate(
        button_status=Case(
            When(to_user__in=request.user.profile.friends.all(), then=Value('none')),
            When(
                from_user=request.user, to_user=F('to_user'),
                then=Value('cancel_request_sent')
            ),
            default=Value('not_friend'),
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    )
    return render(request, 'template.html',context={'friend_requests':friend_requests})

# template

{% for friend_request in friend_requests %}
    {{ friend_request.button_status }}
    {% empty %}
       No users
{% endfor %}
```

I am using [`conditional expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) here.

### Update(based on comments)

It should be simple. You should send data if `request.user.username` and `username` is same. For example:

```
# view

context={'checking_own_friend_list': request.user.username == username,... # rest of the contexts

# template

{% for data in profile_and_button_status %}
    {% empty %}
    {% if checking_own_friend_list %}
    Find people to follow
    {% else %}
    No user
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @ruddra...my code works just as the way I want it, the only problem is that I want to display another text to other user in template.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the updated answer should work. Can you please check?

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, if user A login and have no one following, it should display a text 'Find people to follow', but when user B view on user A following list, it will display a text 'no user' only when user A following list is empty.

Comment: @ruddra..why did you change the context from: User.objects.get(username=username) to request.user.username == username?

Comment: It would make an extra DB query. Instead if you use later, it won't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210727/discussion-between-oghomwen-oguns-and-ruddra).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a for loop instead of an if statement. It should be

```
{% for data in profile_and_button_status %}
    # Button codes here
    {% empty %}
    # why this doesn't display
    {% if data.user != request.user %}
        No users
    {% endif %}
    {% if data.user == request.user %}
        Find people to follow
    {% endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh sorry i made a problem typing, it was actually if not for, I will update my question. I used if and it still not display